# how do you revert 1 or more committed files in mercurial but NOT the entire changeset

Tags: mercurial

Say I have files `File_A`, `File_B` and `File_C`. I edit `File_A` and `File_B` on purpose but `File_C` I just added some debugging code that I don't plan to commit. Then by accident I do a

```
hg commit -m "comment"
```

How do just revert/rollback/backout `File_C`? Basically I'd be happy to be able to go

```
hg update -r <oneRevBack> File_C
hg commit -m "put C back"
```

but update doesn't take a filter AFAIK so it's also going to revert `File_A` and `File_B`. I can copy `File_C` somewhere, `hg update`, then copy it back but that seems lame. Is there a way to do this directly in Mercurial?

Comment: Revert / rollback and / backout are all entirely separe things.  Revert = change in working directory but not repository, rollback = uncommit, and backout = negate the commit.  The answer ranges from impossible (rollback) to easy (backout) depending on what you want.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The exact command you wanted to use would have worked if you used `hg revert` instead of `hg update`

```
hg revert -r .^ File_C
hg commit -m "put C back"
```

Comment: Wouldn't this stomp any subsequent commits to the same file?

Comment: Example, `$ hg revert -r 7428de Libraries/*`.

Comment: If you want to revert from your last commit (most common case) you can do this so you don't need to look up the rev number:
`hg revert -r .^ File_C`

Comment: wow, thanks ! Very usefull when you want to revert a specific file during a merge !!

Comment: If you use zsh with `extendedglob` enabled, you'll need to escape the caret: `'.^'`.

Answer (score 8):

In most cases VonC's solution is just perfect. However, if rollback is no option (e.g. because the commit in question is not the last one or because you did a complex partial commit), then you can do a new commit with the reversed diff of the unwanted changes to `File_C`:

```
hg diff -c REVISION --reverse File_C | hg import -m "Revert changes to File_C" -
```

Where `REVISION` refers to the commit where `File_C` has been committed accidentally. The first command produces the reversed diff for the file in question. It's output is piped to `hg import` (don't forget the trailing `-`).

**UPDATE:** You can also use the *backout* command:

```
hg backout -I File_C REVISION
hg commit -m "Revert changes of File_C in REVISION" File_C
```

The backout command changes your working copy in that it undoes the changes to `File_C` commited in rev. `REVISION`. Afterwards the revert is committed explicitly.

Comment: backout automatically commits.  You can skip that line as I did in my answer.

Comment: @Ry4an: `backout` only commits automatically if the revision to backout is the parent of the working dir - here a simple `rollback`, as suggested by *VonC*, usually does the job. In other cases (which  I refer to in may answer) one needs to commit explicitly. However, thanks for the hint, I'll update my answer to distinguish these backout situations.

Comment: ah, good to know.  I thought it always committed but didn't always merge leaving two heads if the backed out cset wasn't the parent.

Comment: @Ry4an: Yep, it worked like that (leaving 2 heads) before Mercurial 1.7, now the backout command has a slightly (?) different behavior.

Comment: After the backout how do I get the changes back on the local copy?  I accidentally committed and pushed changes to a bunch of files whose changes I didn't want to commit.  So I backed out the commit, but how do I get those files back to the modified state they were in before my accidental commit?

Answer (score 3):

You could use **[`hg rollback`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Rollback)** to undo your last commit, and then re-do it again, this time without the file `C`.
(as mentioned in [Mercurial FAQ](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2BAC8-CommonProblems.I_committed_a_change_containing_nuclear_launch_codes.2C_how_do_I_delete_it_permanently.3F), and also in this [FAQ entry](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2BAC8-TechnicalDetails.What_is_the_difference_between_rollback_and_strip.3F) where it is noted that "there is no backup when you rollback a transaction", so use it with caution)

Answer (score 3):

```
hg revert FILE -r REVISION
```

you can revert it to last commit via

```
hg revert FILE -r .~1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use interactive mode:

```
hg revert -i -r .^
```

Select what you want **reverted** and confirm.

```
hg amend
```