# hg: How do I revert (a single file) several commits back?

Tags: mercurial, revert

The closest answer is [**this one**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101013/how-do-you-revert-1-or-more-committed-files-in-mercurial-but-not-the-entire-chan), and here's a line from it:

```
hg revert -r <oneRevBack> fileName
```

The last thing is to get `<oneRevBack>` other than using hash. I would dream of just typing `<-1>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hg syntax for "one rev back" is `tip^`, where `tip` is the latest revision and `^` means "parent". If your working directory is not at tip, use `.^`, where the dot means "current revision".

You can use `hg revert -r tip~n file` to revert to the `n`th ancestor of the tip (using the first parent if a commit has two parents). You can use `-(n+1)` only if there's only a single branch. `-1` refers to the last revision, `-2` the penultimate revision, and so forth, in order of revision numbering and not following the branch structure. (See `hg help revsets` for more details.)