# How to undo local changes to a specific file

Tags: git, git-revert

I'm trying to undo local changes to a specific file. Nothing has been committed.

When I want to revert all changes, I can perform `git revert --reset HEAD`. However, in this case, I don't want to revert all changes to all files.

Its not clear or obvious to me how to revert just a file, even after reading the `git-revert(3)` man page:

```
NAME
       git-revert - Revert some existing commits

SYNOPSIS
       git revert [--[no-]edit] [-n] [-m parent-number] [-s] <commit>...
       git revert --continue
       git revert --quit
       git revert --abort
...
```

This is similar to [How to revert a specific file in a old commit on git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27388076), but no commits have been performed. And unlike OP, who wants to go back to an arbitrary commit, I just want the file to return to MASTER's copy of it.

Under SVN, I would just delete the file in question and then perform a `svn update`.

How do I revert changes to a single file?

Comment: uh `git checkout -- <file>` ?

Comment: Thanks NightShadeQueen. I did not checkout. I'm using the default work space provided by git. That is, I performed a `git clone` and then went to work.

Answer (score 722, accepted):

You don't want `git revert`. That undoes a previous commit. You want `git checkout` to get git's version of the file from master.

`git checkout -- filename.txt`

In general, when you want to perform a git operation on a single file, use `-- filename`.

---

- [git-checkout Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutemlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203)
- [git-revert Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)

---

**2020 Update**

Git [introduced](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ae92ac8ae3838e72840f5d019195bb9c0c9e7b0e/Documentation/RelNotes/2.23.0.txt#L61-L65) a new command `git restore` in version `2.23.0`. Therefore, if you have git version `2.23.0+`, you can simply `git restore filename.txt` - which does the same thing as `git checkout -- filename.txt`. The docs for this command do note that it is currently experimental.

- [git-restore Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore)

Comment: I did not checkout. I'm using the default work space provided by git. That is, I performed a `git clone` and then went to work.

Comment: Doesn't matter. That command will still work. You implicitly checkout whichever branch you cloned. Also, run `git status` There should be a one-liner explaining how to revert unstaged changes. `(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)`

Comment: `git checkout -- "my file name with spaces.txt"` - Use double quotes enclosing your file name in case it has spaces.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Still says "error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge"

Comment: @Coxy Can't help without a lot more info. Perhaps open a new question about why `git checkout -- filename` isn't working for you. Include a reference to what you tried from this question. Also include the output of `git status` and the other commands that you're running.

Comment: This can be confusing for users coming from Mercurial because the mercurial command is `hg revert  ...`. Although there is a `git revert` command, it performs an entirely different task from `hg revert`.

Comment: Why is `--` needed ? I did `git checkout file.txt` and achieved the same thing

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga it is not strictly required. It is used for [Argument Disambiguation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_argument_disambiguation) (to resolve conflicts between branch names and file names). If you provide it, the arguments after it will always be interpreted as filenames, which is desired here.

Comment: Please make sure that you have space after -- . `git checkout -- (space) filename`

Comment: Upvoted, because I'm not a fan of the suggested duplicate solution. The suggested solution has 13 answers, overwhelming for someone unfamiliar with git. Basically the reason is the use of `checkout` which is seriously counter intuitive.

Comment: `git checkout` cycles through changed files with tab key whereas `git restore` does not. Or am I missing something?

Comment: `git checkout` or `git restore` does not work if the local change is to remove the file. In that situation, the only thing I've found which works is to `git reset` the file and _then_ `git restore` the file...